# console.trace() not showing all the traces in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

For some reason `console.trace()` doesn't show all traces in Electron application

```js
function test ()
{
  setTimeout(() => console.trace("test"));
}

test();
```

If you run this snippet and than open browser console, it shows 1 trace line, but if you run it again while console already opened, it shows 4 lines of traces:

[image]

In Electron it only shows 1 line:

[image]

Any ideas why this happening and how to fix it?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/vanowm/421760821ed30fb32d81fb9f5ac304d1) is [electron fiddle](https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle) I'm testing it with

Comment: I only see one line in my browser (chrome).

Comment: did you run the the snippet while console was opened? or you opened console afterwards?

Comment: oh interesting - I opened console *after* running the snippet. If I do it backwards, I do see more lines for some reason